# How to apply background color for a full page in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

How to apply background color for a full page in ionic

[image]

I used a code HTML

```
<ion-content padding class="bg.style">
```

in css

```
.bg-style {
 background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

but I didn't get output please help me

Comment: which version of ionic is this? Ionic 3 or 4? Will you be able to share your code (html + scss/css)

Comment: please change the class name to `bg-style` in html. That's the name you declared in css file. not `bg.style`

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
    <ion-item>
  <div class="item-content">
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

The Ionic CSS contains a CSS property:

```
 .item-content {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

The inline CSS you added is being applied to the element behind the element with the #ffffff background, so you can't see your background color.

Apply the background color to the .item-content element, as by adding the following CSS to the Ionic CSS file, or create a custom CSS file and include a  to it in the header, with the following:

```
 .item .item-content {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Here's the [working.demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/f6e905d33b7c)